# Making function calls exclusive per block

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.7.x

I have the requirement that in my smart contract certain functions cannot be called, if another function already has been called inside the same contract during the same transaction.
Imagine I have the functions A, B and C. If function A or B is called, function C should not be callable inside the same transaction.

This is my approach so far: When A or B is called, store the following values with a modifier

- `tx.origin`: I can't rely on `msg.sender`, as someone could deploy 2 smart contracts in one transaction, call A with one contract and C with the other
- `block.number`

when C is called, check if `tx.origin` and `block.number` are the same as the stored values and revert if necessary.

This should ensure that C cannot be called if A or B were called in the same block by the same person. Is there a flaw in my logic here?

Comment: The title of the question says 'per block' and the body of the question says 'per transaction'. Those are two different requirements, which one is it that you actually need?

Comment: I need it per transaction, as I don't see how this is possible, I wanted to work this out for 'per block' first, as this is sufficient

Comment: It's actually harder per block than it is per transaction. See [OZ (very simple) implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol).

Comment: The reentrancy guard only protects against calling another function again, while the function has not finished executing. An attacker could call A first and after A finished executing, they could call C without a problem